# Equivalence of dual space of normed space X and continuously differentiable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Define that two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent if there exists bounded linear maps $A: X \to Y$ and $B: Y \to X$ such that $A$ and $B$ are inverses of each other. How do you show that there is no normed space $X$ such that that it's dual space $X$' is equivalent to the space of continuously differentiable functions from $[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ with the sup norm?

Comment: This is the reason that we often use a different norm for the space $C^1$.  A norm so that it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: equivalence preserves completeness, and the dual space is always complete...

Comment: Is that true for this definition of equivalence also, not just for equivalent norms on the same space?

Comment: If so, how do you show that this equivalence preserves completeness?

Comment: Assume $X$ is complete and $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Since $B$ is bounded, it is not hard to show $x_n=By_n$ is Cauchy and hence converges. By continuity of $A$ this implies $y_n$ converges.